# I trigger recording when power of current sample is X dB greater than last Y samples, what is the terminology here?

Tags: audio

Doing time domain processing of incoming audio. I sample the power level every 0.25s and keeping a running average of intensity over 5 samples. When the power level of the current sample is 10dB greater than the moving average, we start recording.

What are the correct names for these numbers? I also use the same method to trigger recording stop. Is this the same terminology?

I have the code and will use your suggestion to name the variables correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: (It's often useful to keep a recording buffer of the last few seconds of audio, so that when the trigger is hit, you have the time immediately *before* the trigger recorded, too.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Running average" is fine. You can also call it the [moving average](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

I suppose you could call the variable associated with the 10dB number the *signal detection threshold*.